# Can strace tell me where in my code a syscall is called?

Tags: debugging, strace

I'm trying to debug why [ngspice](http://ngspice.sourceforge.net/) prints annoying newlines to *stderr* while running a simulation. I'm trying to locate it in one of the 2400 source files tracing back to 1993 but it's not as easy as it sounds! It does however mean that I have a binary with all debug information embedded.

My first idea was that [strace](https://strace.io/) could help me locate what I believe is the offending call and trace it back to the source code. For example, I'm pretty sure that this is the offending syscall:

```
   brk(0x55d1a84e9000)                     = 0x55d1a84e9000                                                                                                                                         
   clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=61462905}) = 0                                                                                                                        
>> write(2, "\n", 1)                       = 1                                                                                                                                                      
   getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, {ru_utime={tv_sec=0, tv_usec=26269}, ru_stime={tv_sec=0, tv_usec=35243}, ...}) = 0                                                                                        
   openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/self/statm", O_RDONLY) = 3
```

I had hoped that if I traced an executable that had debug information, strace would show me the place in the source code, but that did not happen automatically and the manual is a little overwhelming.

I found a section in the manual called **Tracing** but couldn't find anything specific.

Is it possible with *strace*, and if so: How? If not, do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using gdb, you can set conditional syscall catchpoints based on the args to the system call (analogous to the way you'd set conditional breakpoints on entry to a function based on the args to the function call). Then, when the catchpoint is triggered, you can see where the caller is (file name, line number, and source code).

Here's an example for x86_64.

```
$ cat gtest.c
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
        write(1, "text\n", 5);
        write(2, "text2\n", 6);
        write(2, "\n", 1);
        return 0;
}

$ cc gtest.c -g -o gtest
```

```
$ gdb -q gtest
Reading symbols from gtest...done.
(gdb) list
1       #include <unistd.h>
2       int main()
3       {
4               write(1, "text\n", 5);
5               write(2, "text2\n", 6);
6               write(2, "\n", 1);
7               return 0;
8       }
(gdb) catch syscall write
Catchpoint 1 (syscall 'write' [1])
(gdb) condition 1 $rdi == 2 && *(char *)$rsi == '\n' && $rdx == 1
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/mp/gtest
text
text2

Catchpoint 1 (call to syscall write), 0x00007fffff13b970 in __write_nocancel ()
    at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
84      ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fffff13b970 in __write_nocancel () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
#1  0x00000000080006f6 in main () at gtest.c:6
(gdb) up
#1  0x00000000080006f6 in main () at gtest.c:6
6               write(2, "\n", 1);
(gdb)
```

Comment: While this doesn't answer my question literally, it's IMO the "best" solution to my problem, and the one I ended up getting the most value out of. Catching the syscall in gdb is more powerful.

Answer (score 12):

Obvious in hindsight, but one very useful flag is `-k`. From the man-page:

> -k          Print the execution stack trace of the traced processes after each system call.

This needs a binary with debug information, and it will get extremely noisy, but combined with a simple filter (`-e write` in this case) you will eventually get something that looks like this:

```
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
 > /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.28.so(__write+0x14) [0xea504]
 > /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.28.so(_IO_file_write+0x2d) [0x7b3bd]
 > /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.28.so(_IO_file_setbuf+0xef) [0x7a75f]
 > /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.28.so(_IO_do_write+0x19) [0x7c509]
 > /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.28.so(_IO_file_overflow+0x103) [0x7c8f3]
 > /home/pipe/src/ngspice/debug/src/ngspice(OUTendPlot+0x1ae) [0xd7643]
 > /home/pipe/src/ngspice/debug/src/ngspice(DCop+0x167) [0x4cd788]
 > /home/pipe/src/ngspice/debug/src/ngspice(CKTdoJob+0x428) [0x4c70dd]
 > /home/pipe/src/ngspice/debug/src/ngspice(if_run+0x3b9) [0xe5d3e]
 > /home/pipe/src/ngspice/debug/src/ngspice(dosim+0x428) [0xe02ee]
```

From this I could eventually find the right place after tracking some function inline optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

> My first idea was that [strace](https://strace.io/) could help me locate what I believe is the offending call and trace it back to the source code.

You guessed right, but must have overlooked this in the [`strace`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) manual page:

`-i          Print the instruction pointer at the time of the system call.`

Comment: But how can the instruction pointer be used to trace it to the source code? That information is lost as soon as the program ends right? Since this is a command line tool, the program ends immediately. When testing I see for example `[00007fb9b9bba504] write(2, "\n", 1) = 1`.

Comment: Ah, I missed that the values can differ from run to run. - Well, in the meantime you got more helpful answers.